# How to load specific data as colors from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

hi guys am trying to load data from JSON file and i wanna use it as background for each block that get fitch

so the block is a box and each box have 4 small boxs and i wanna target these 4 boxs and changes there background color based on the JSON file data

here is the JSON format i use

```
[
  {
  "name" : "color1" ,
  "box1" : "#7f6ded" ,
  "box2" : "#343434" ,
  "box3" : "#ffffff" ,
  "box4" : "#858585"
  } ,
  {
  "name" : "color2" ,
  "box1" : "#58c9b9" ,
  "box2" : "#343434" ,
  "box3" : "#ffffff" ,
  "box4" : "#9dc8c8"
  }
]
```

and the here is the calling jq

```
$(function () {

  // start calling colors
  $.getJSON( "js/colors.json", function( data ) {

    // console.log(data[1].box1);
    var output = "";
    var output2 = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      output +=
                "<div class=" + "col-md-4" + ">" +
                "<div class=" + "co-palet" + ">" +
                "<div class=" + "box box-1" + "></div>" +
                "<div class=" + "box box-2" + "></div>" +
                "<div class=" + "box box-3" + "></div>" +
                "<div class=" + "box box-4" + "></div>"
                + "</div>" + "</div>"

      $('#myColors').html(output);      
    };

  });
  // end calling colors



});
```

and i output into

```
<div id="myColors"></div>
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: inside for loop `alert(data[i].name);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you might as well use the `$.each` method for better performance. Hope this helps!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON( "datos.json", function( data ) {

    var output = "";
    $.each(data, function (val, ob) {
        output +=
            "<div class=\"col-md-4\">" +
            "<div class=\"co-palet\">" +
            "<div class=\"box box-1\" style=\"background-color:" + ob.box1 + "\">"+ ob.box1+"</div>" +
            "<div class=\"box box-2\" style=\"background-color:" + ob.box2 + "\">"+ ob.box2+"</div>" +
            "<div class=\"box box-3\" style=\"background-color:" + ob.box3 + "\">"+ ob.box3+"</div>" +
            "<div class=\"box box-4\" style=\"background-color:" + ob.box4 + "\">"+ ob.box4+"</div>"
            + "</div>" + "</div>";
    });

    $('#myColors').html(output);
});
// end calling colors
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "name" : "color1" ,
    "box1" : "#7f6ded" ,
    "box2" : "#343434" ,
    "box3" : "#ffffff" ,
    "box4" : "#858585"
  },
  {
    "name" : "color2" ,
    "box1" : "#58c9b9" ,
    "box2" : "#343434" ,
    "box3" : "#ffffff" ,
    "box4" : "#9dc8c8"
  }
];

var output = '',
    colors = '';

$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
  var colorID = '#' + value.name + ' ';

  output += '<div class="col-md-4">\
<div class="col-palet" id="' + value.name + '">';

  $.each(value, function(i, v) {
    output += (i != 'name') ? '<div class="box ' + i + '"></div>' : '';
    colors += (i != 'name') ? colorID + '.' + i + ' {background:' + v + '}\n': '';
  });

  output += '</div></div>';
});

$('#myColors').html(output);
$('#stylus').text(colors);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="stylus"></style>
<div id="myColors"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the json objects and then instead of passing the class, pass the color as a style:

```
$.getJSON( "js/colors.json", function( data ) {

// console.log(data[1].box1);
var output = "";
var output2 = "";
```

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

```
                output +=
                    '<div class="col-md-4">' +
                    '<div class="co-palet">' +
                    '<div class = "box" style = "background :' + 
                     data[0].box1 + '"></div>' +
                    '<div class = "box" style = "background :' + 
                     data[0].box2 + '"></div>' +
                    '<div class = "box" style = "background :' + 
                     data[0].box3 + '"></div>' +
                    '<div class = "box" style = "background :' + 
                     data[0].box4 + '"></div>' +
                    + '</div></div>';

              $('#myColors').html(output);      
            };
```

});

If you prefer to use double quotes to build strings, maybe try to escape the double quotes you want to be in the string like \" this.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Just add a style attribute to your boxes.

```
$.getJSON( "js/colors.json", function( data ) {

  var output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    output +=
            "<div class=\"col-md-4\">" +
            "<div class=\"co-palet\">" +
            "<div class=\"box box-1\" style=\"background-color:" + data[i].box1 + "\"></div>" +
            "<div class=\"box box-2\" style=\"background-color:" + data[i].box2 + "\"></div>" +
            "<div class=\"box box-3\" style=\"background-color:" + data[i].box3 + "\"></div>" +
            "<div class=\"box box-4\" style=\"background-color:" + data[i].box4 + "\"></div>"
            + "</div>" + "</div>";

  };
  $('#myColors').html(output); //move this outside the loop so it isn't overwritten every time
});
```

Also, make sure to properly escape your quotes.

Comment: your life saver mate :)